# Sample more than one element from multivariable normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, distribution, normal-distribution

I have a 2D means matrix in size `n*m`, where `n` is number of samples and `m` is the dimension of the data.
I have as well `n` matrices of `m*m`, namely sigma is my variance matrix in shape `n*m*m`.
I wish to sample `n` samples from a the distributions above, such that `x_i~N(mean[i], sigma[i])`.
Any way to do that in `numpy` or any other standard lib w/o running with a for loop?

The only option I thought was using `np.random.multivariate_normal()` by flatting the means matrix to one vector, and flatten the 3D sigma to a 2D blocks-diagonal matrix. And of course reshape afterwards.  But that means we are going the sample with sigma in shape `(n*m)*(n*m)` which can easily be ridiculously huge, and only computing and allocating that matrix (if possible) can take longer than running in a for loop.

In my specific task, right now Sigma is the same matrix for all the samples, means I can express Sigma in `m*m`, and it is the same one for all n points. But I am interested in a general solution.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to tell without testable code, but this should be close:

```
A = numpy.linalg.cholesky(sigma)                # => shape (n, m, m), same as sigma
Z = np.random.normal(size = (n, m))             # shape (n, m)
X = np.einsum('ijk, ik -> ij', A, Z) + mean     # shape (n, m)
```

What's going on:

We're manually sampling multivariate normal distributions according to the standard Cholesky decomposition method outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector).  `A` is built such that `A@A.T = sigma`. Then `X` (the multivariate normal) can be formed by the dot product of `A` and a univariate normal *N(0, 1)* vector `Z`, plus the `mean`.

You keep the extraneous dimension throughout the calculation in the first (index = 0, `'i'` in the `einsum`) axis, while contracting the last (`'k'`) axis, forming the dot product.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why numpy doesn't do it built in np.random.multivariate_random() in cases dim(mean) != 1 instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Because it's built internally as `X = A@Z + mean` and that doesn't work unless everything stays in 1- and 2-space.  I *hate* that as someone who works in higher-dimensional state spaces, but since the vast majority of `numpy`'s userbase doesn't know any tensor math above 2-space (matrices) everything is streamlined to 2-space and doing anything higher-d is left to the user to handle manually using `einsum`

Comment: btw, I have a similar question (maybe should open a new one), If I have my own custom distribution (1D array not negative that sums to 1) and I want to sample from it, no problem with np.random.choice(). If I have a matrix of distribution, namely each column is a distribution vector, and I want to sample from each vector, any way to do that w/o a for loop?

Comment: Please write another question, and try to include a [mcve] this time.  I'm not a particularly good mind-reader.